# Resources in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Can I create a list of resources (e.g. people) and assign them to tasks? At least partially, without partial assignment and all other whistles.

I want it to be somewhat like it is in MS Project.

Comment: There’s no specific support for resource assignment, but you can use tags (or properties) for the assignee and an “assigned” TODO state for something like this. You might want to then look at customizing an agenda view or column view.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [ox-taskjuggler](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/taskjuggler/ox-taskjuggler.html) quite comprehensive for project planning, including visualization with Gantt charts, etc. It allows you to map org properties to taskjuggler concepts like resources.

Comment: It is a little alarming that it's written in Ruby, but looks like definitely worth trying. Thanks!